# Needing to remove a Hikashop Category that is generated on the homepage

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

The website I am referring to is http://www.omhprintshop.com, and I'm needing to remove the 'Ambassador' box that was generated. I can't seem to find the possible snippet for this. I have removed the category once with jQuery, but it still leaves that block where the li is in place.

The li class for that is specifically

```
<li class="col-sm-4 hikashop_category hikashop_category_column_3 hikashop_category_row_3"></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in browser console

```
jQuery('a[title=Ambassadors]').closest('li').remove()
```